# How to display cart items length in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, variable-length

I WooCommerce I would like to display the length of the items in the cart.

How to display cart items length in WooCommerce?

Maybe there is a shortcode for that?

Comment: Hey there, I was expecting some feed back on the answer below please.

Answer (score 0):

To display the product length on cart items, use the `WC_Product` `get_length()` method as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_cart_item_length', 20, 2 );
function display_cart_item_length( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    $product_length = $cart_item['data']->get_length();

    if( ! empty($product_length) ){
        $cart_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'Length', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => wc_format_localized_decimal($product_length) . ' ' . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' )
        );
    }
    return $cart_data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Or if you want to get total items length and display it in cart and checkout use;

```
// Shortcode to get cart items total length formatted for display
add_shortcode( 'items_total_length', 'wc_get_cart_items_total_length' );
function wc_get_cart_items_total_length(){
    $total_length = 0; // Initializing variable

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product_length = $cart_item['data']->get_length(); // Get producct length

        if( ! empty($product_length) ){
            $total_length += $product_length * $cart_item['quantity']; // Sum item length x quantity
        }
    }
    return wc_format_localized_decimal($total_length) . ' ' . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' );
}

// Display total length in cart and checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total', 'display_cart_total_length' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'display_cart_total_length' );
function display_cart_total_length() {
    echo '<tr class="length-total">
        <th>' . esc_html__( 'Length', 'woocommerce' ) . '</th>
        <td>' . do_shortcode("[items_total_length]") . '</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works